# Проблема со строкой, jsonAPIDetail.setLogin(arguments?.getString("userLogin")!!) - IllegalArgumentException: Service methods cannot return void

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, gson, rxjava2

Класс User

```
class User {

var login : String = ""
var id : Int = 0
var avatar_url : String = ""
var followers : Int = 0
var name : String = ""
var public_repos : Int = 0
var public_gists : Int = 0 }
```

Retrofit клиент

```
object RetrofitClient {
private var myInstance: Retrofit? = null

val instance: Retrofit
    get() {
        if (myInstance == null) {
                myInstance = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build()
            }
            return myInstance!!
        }}
```

Интерфейс

```
interface IUserDetailAPI {

@GET("users/{login}")
fun setLogin(@Path( "login") login: String)
val user: Observable<User>}
```

Класс Фрагмент

```
class FragmentUserDetail : Fragment() {

lateinit var jsonAPIDetail: IUserDetailAPI
lateinit var compositeDisposableDetail: CompositeDisposable

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_detail_info, null)
    val retrofit = RetrofitClient.instance
    jsonAPIDetail = retrofit.create(IUserDetailAPI::class.java) 

    jsonAPIDetail.setLogin(arguments?.getString("userLogin")!!) //********************* ТУТ ПРОБЛЕМА *************************

    fetchData()
    return itemView
}

private fun fetchData() {
    compositeDisposableDetail = CompositeDisposable()

    compositeDisposableDetail
        .add(jsonAPIDetail.user
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe{user->setUserFields(user)}
    )
}

private fun setUserFields(userInfo: User) {...}
```

Comment: Проблема решена и в коде уже рабочий вариант, всем спасибо. Ошибка была `interface IUserDetailAPI` была лишняя переменная, а так в обращении к методу `login` при добавлении в compositeDisposableDetail

Comment: Если проблема решена, добавьте ответом, а не изменяйте вопрос.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 1):

В ошибке все написано.
Методы интерфейса для Retrofit не могут ничего не возвращать.
Это должен быть как минимум `Call<ResponseBody>`

```
fun setLogin(@Path( "login") login: String): Call<ResponseBody>
```

Comment: Я пробовал использовать  `Completable / Call<ResponseBody> / Call<User> / Call<String> / Single / String`  после этого возникает ошибка в строке с методом add*

    `compositeDisposableDetail.add(jsonAPIDetail.user`

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException: HTTP method annotation is required (e.g., @GET, @POST, etc.).`

Comment: Если это тоже методы интерфейса Retrofit, добавьте аннотации. Если нет, уберите из интерфейса.

Comment: Если респонс не важен, то можно использовать возвращаемый тип Call<Void>

Answer (score 0):

РЕШЕНО...

1. В интерфейсе  удаляем `val user: Observable<User>` и меняем метод setLogin -> `fun login(@Path( "login") login: String): Single<User>`
2. В классе фрагмент удаляем эту строку `jsonAPIDetail.setLogin(arguments?.getString("userLogin")!!)`
3. В методе `fetchData()` меняем параметр `.add(jsonAPIDetail.user` на это `.add(jsonAPIDetail.login(arguments?.getString("userLogin")!!)`

**Ниже уже исправленный код**

Интерфейс

```
    interface IUserDetailAPI {

    @GET("users/{login}")
    fun login(@Path( "login") login: String) : Single<User>}
```

Класс Фрагмент

```
    class FragmentUserDetail : Fragment() {

    lateinit var jsonAPIDetail: IUserDetailAPI
    lateinit var compositeDisposableDetail: CompositeDisposable

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_detail_info, null)
        val retrofit = RetrofitClient.instance
        jsonAPIDetail = retrofit.create(IUserDetailAPI::class.java) 

        fetchData()
        return itemView
    }

    private fun fetchData() {
        compositeDisposableDetail = CompositeDisposable()

        compositeDisposableDetail
            .add(jsonAPIDetail..login(arguments?.getString("userLogin")!!)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe{user->setUserFields(user)}
        )
    }

    private fun setUserFields(userInfo: User) {...}
```